# I get an Android.Views.InflateException when I use SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main) that includes tabs

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I get an `Android.Views.InflateException` when I use `setContentView (Resource.Layout.Main)` that includes tabs and  can't understand why.

I've been trying to find others with my problem, but it seems that `Android.Views.InflateException` is a very general error message, because people seems to get it in all kinds of situations. I've tried some of the things I've seen mentioned, but they haven't helped me so far.

The weird thing is that the exact same `Main.axml` code works perfectly in a different trial application, but I can't get it to work in this one.

I'm fairly new at programming applications and I don't know if it makes any difference, but I'm using **Xamarin Studio**. I've tried a few other simple applications to get used all the new things and they have worked without much trouble.

This is the code for my main Launcher:

```
using System;

using System.IO;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
//using Mono.Data.Sqlite;

namespace MultiFuncTest1
{
    [Activity (MainLauncher=true, Label="@string/app_name", Theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar")]
    public class MultiFuncTest1 : TabActivity
    {

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            // Set the view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);


            // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            //                                                  TABS
            // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            // Declares TabSpec and Intent
            TabHost.TabSpec spec;
            Intent intent;

            // Creates and Intent To Start and Activity for the Image-tab.
            intent = new Intent (this, typeof (ImageActivity));
            intent.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.NewTask);

            // Starts a TabSpec for the Image-tab and adds it to the TabHost
            spec = TabHost.NewTabSpec ("image");
            spec.SetIndicator ("Image", Resources.GetDrawable (Resource.Drawable.Icon));
            spec.SetContent (Intent);
            TabHost.AddTab (spec);

            // Creates and Intent To Start and Activity for the Icon-tab.
            intent = new Intent (this, typeof (IconActivity));
            intent.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.NewTask);

            // Starts a TabSpec for the Icon-tab and adds it to the TabHost
            spec = TabHost.NewTabSpec ("icons");
            spec.SetIndicator ("Icons", Resources.GetDrawable (Resource.Drawable.Icon));
            spec.SetContent (Intent);
            TabHost.AddTab (spec);

            // Creates and Intent To Start and Activity for the Image-tab.
            intent = new Intent (this, typeof (ItemListActivity));
            intent.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.NewTask);

            // Starts a TabSpec for the Image-tab and adds it to the TabHost
            spec = TabHost.NewTabSpec ("itemList");
            spec.SetIndicator ("Item List", Resources.GetDrawable (Resource.Drawable.Icon));
            spec.SetContent (Intent);
            TabHost.AddTab (spec);

            // Creates and Intent To Start and Activity for the Image-tab.
            intent = new Intent (this, typeof (WebLinkActivity));
            intent.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.NewTask);

            // Starts a TabSpec for the Image-tab and adds it to the TabHost
            spec = TabHost.NewTabSpec ("webLink");
            spec.SetIndicator ("Web Links", Resources.GetDrawable (Resource.Drawable.Icon));
            spec.SetContent (Intent);
            TabHost.AddTab (spec);

            TabHost.CurrentTab = 1;
        }

    }


}
```

This is the code for my ImageActivity which is supposed to be one of the tabs. All the tab-activities have very similar codes at the moment as I'm just trying to get the outline to work:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace MultiFuncTest1
{
    [Activity (Label = "ImageActivity")]
    public class ImageActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);

            //SetContentView (Resource.Layout.ImagePage);

            TextView textview = new TextView (this);
            textview.Text = "This is the Artists tab";
            SetContentView (textview);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my `Main.axml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

and the `ImagePage.axml` which will be one of the tabs. the other tabs looks very similar at the moment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/Icon"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/iPimageView1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the first part of the Stack Trace I get. After the "End of managed exception stack trace" part the trace continues for a long time and ends with something like "and 250 more rows" or something like that so I assume those aren't as important? If they'll help just tell me so and I'll add them as well:

```
Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class <unknown>
at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (intptr,intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue[]) [0x00024] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-lion-bs1/03814ac5/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:616
at Android.App.Activity.SetContentView (int) [0x0006b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-lion-bs1/03814ac5/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-8/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:3119
at MultiFuncTest1.MultiFuncTest1.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) [0x00009] in d:\Mobile App Dev\Projects\MultiFuncTest1\MultiFuncTest1\MultiFuncTest1.cs:24
at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00010] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-lion-bs1/03814ac5/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-8/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:1490
at at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.46f87726-02c8-486d-b95c-c7cce7c7d106 (intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00017, 0x00043>
at 
at --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
```

I hope someone can help me understand the problem here, I would really like get a grasp on what I might be doing wrong...

Comment: Its R.Layout.main not resource.

Comment: @Arju The author is not using Java. So there might be difference in code.

Comment: Sorry theres no tag as java

Comment: Sorry for not explaining this in my question, but no I'm not using Java. Xamarin studio is based on Mono which uses C# to create cross-platform applications.

Comment: After trying some different ways to solve this I've at least figured out that it seems to be some kind of error with the "Resource". The thing is, I've used Resource in the same way in all my previous application trials. It works when I change the Main.axml to a regular LinearLayout, and it works in a different application with tabs but not here. When I debug I get "Unknown identifier: Resource". I've also tried using R or Resources instead but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Your ImagePage.axml doesn't need the TabHost and TabWidget tags; you should only have those in your Main.axml.  The layout for your tabs will be contained in the FrameLayout in Main.axml, so each tab layout file only ne

Comment: This was an error in copying the code to this question. The correct code for ImagePage.axml should now be visable.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem myself after some more searching, it was in my main launcher. Th problem was that I was trying to call the class "Intent" in the "spec.SetContent (Intent);" line while creating each class, while what I should've been calling was my instance of it, "intent" (without a capital "i"). So basically it was a misspelling, but it didn't show up as I syntax error since there was a class with the same name...

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

This might be pretty irrelevant but whoever is still wondering where this error could be coming from - might point you in the right direction.

I had the same issue, turned out that the custom control I was referring to from within AXML had a wrong path specified, i. e. control was nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 0):

i have encountered this problem so many times,

This particular exception is thrown when you don't define your THEME within your activity. you are supposed to have something like this

```
[Activity (Label = "ImageActivity", Theme="@style/yourtheme")]
```

Answer (score 0):

i have encountered this problem so many times,

This particular exception is thrown when you don't define your THEME within your activity. you are supposed to have something like this

[Activity (Label = "ImageActivity", Theme="@styles/yourtheme")]

**#### In visual studio  the file name of style is styles.xml not style.xml**